# synchronization between branches in visual studio 2015 and in web

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

it's clear when you see this pics. sorry im not good at eng. so it's a little bit hard to understand what i write it here.
git branches in website and branches in team Explorer of VS2015 aren't synchronized. aint same.

**BECAUSE**

we two person are working together. my remotes/origin in VS and branch in web was same at first. The problem happens when after below story.

1. I changed code in hotfix-2.0.0.a branch in local and clicked the Synchronization section in VS and 'pushed' my commits to remote. and clicked the 'Sync' button. (I thought that I did send commits I've done of remotes\origin in local to xxx.visualstudio.com)
2. I made a 'pull request' in the web. (hotfix-2.0.0.a to develop and Release)
3. we 'approved' and 'completed' in the web.(I think 'complete'  let automatically merged to branch I selected)
4. As you know, branches hotfix-2.0.0 was deleted. and He who is my coworker deleted branches that Hotfix, Feature. He said I made them wrong. these are useless.

**summary**: he deleted Feature, Hotfix, hotfix-2.0.0.a(merged and deleted) in web.
but my branches remotes/origin in VS in local didn't get updated from web. cuz there are still remained in my remotes/origin that is shown.

I deldeted them in local then VS said 
"푸시하는 동안 다음 오류가 보고되었습니다.(means error occured while pushing)
    refs/heads/hotfix-2.0.0.a, TF401027: Your identity (Windows Live ID\xx@xx.xx.kr) doesn't have the Git 'ForcePush' permission for the current branch, which you need for the action you just tried. Contact your administrator for help."
But I don't want ForcePush. just want to sync with view in web.

could you guys tell me how can i solve it? 
thx for read it. thx a lot.

[git branches in team Explorer of VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmB9x.png)

this first pic's point spot i want to show you is remotes/origin.

[git branches in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IKxf.png)

in this sencond pic, there are 4 branches.

now first pic there are 7 remote repo, and second pic there are 4 remote repo.

Coworker deleted some branches or merged in website. but remotes/origin/branches doesn't show these changes. Is there any way to synchronize between remotes/origin in local and in web about changes of branches?

Comment: Do you understand how Git works? If not, start there.

Comment: @DanielMann okay thx. i think i need to study git more times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this problem. I've tried to fetch, and push but it doesn't work.  However when I click the 'sync' in Synchronization tab in team explorer, I can delete the branch in Branch tab in team explorer which was already deleted in the web site.

Thx all of guys.

Answer (score 0):

- "Push branch" to push local branch to the remote
- "Fetch" or "Checkout" to fetch/checkout the branches from the remote repo

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For branches `Feature`, `Hotfix`,`hotfix-2.0`, you can delete them by this way:

1. In Sync, click fetch.
2. In Branches, delete these branches (`Feature`, `Hotfix`,`hotfix-2.0`) in remotes/origin: select a branch in remotes/origin -> right click -> delete branch from remote.

[image]

3. In branches, delete the local branches (`Feature`, `Hotfix`,`hotfix-2.0`, `feature-2.0.5`): select a branch –> right click -> Delete.

Comment: I added Err msg from VS I omitted before to my Questions and some story in detail like you step by step illustration that i got touched.  VS said I need a permission of ForcePush. but I don't want it I just sync local repo with web repo. 
I 'm really happy to be given your answer.

Comment: Please fetch in VS first, and then delete useless branches. If you still can't delete these branches, you need to check if you have permission to delete branches for the VSTS git repo.

Comment: Can you delete these useless branches now?